# Vue.js - Transfer objects between two selects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following HTML with 2 selects and 2 buttons to transfer options between the selects:

```
<div class="col-xs-1" style="width:45%">
    <label for="txtDescricao">Motivos</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="todosMotivos" v-model="Motivos_selected" style="width: 100%;">
        <option v-for="motivo in Motivos" v-bind:value="motivo.Codigo">{{motivo.Descricao}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 text-center align-middle" style="width:10%">
    <br />
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-arrow-right" v-on:click.prevent="adicionarItensSelect"></button></p>
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-arrow-left" v-on:click.prevent="removerItensSelect"></button></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1" style="width:45%">
    <label for="txtDescricao">Motivos vinculados</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="selectedMotivos" v-model="Motivos_vinculados_selected" style="width: 100%;">
        <option v-for="motivo in Motivos_vinculados" v-bind:value="motivo.Codigo">{{motivo.Descricao}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the vue app data:

```
Motivos: [],
Motivos_selected: [],
Motivos_vinculados: [],
Motivos_vinculados_selected: [],
```

The list of "Motivos" is being loaded this way:

```
getMotivos: function (motivosVinculados) {
    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Motivo/GetMotivos",

        success: function (data) {
            self.Motivos = data.motivos;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Erro ao executar operação.');
        }
    });
},
```

I am trying to transfer the selected options to the second Select this way:

```
adicionarItensSelect: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Motivos_vinculados.push(self.Motivos_selected);
},
```

But, instead, the option goes blank to the second Select:
[image]

I think the item is not going to the second Select as the same object. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Hi @Taian  can you replicate this problem on jfiddle ?

Comment: Hi @MazinoSUkah ! Follow the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kopq6x2f/

Comment: Please check my answer and see if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the object to the options like so:

```
<option v-for="motivo in Motivos" v-bind:value="motivo>{{motivo.Descricao}}</option>
```

```js
var appEquipamento = new Vue({
    el: "#equipamentoApp",
    data: {
        Motivos: [
         { Codigo: 1, Descricao: "Motivo 1" },
         { Codigo: 2, Descricao: "Motivo 2" },
          { Codigo: 3, Descricao: "Motivo 3" }
        ],
        Motivos_selected: [],
        Motivos_vinculados: [],
        Motivos_vinculados_selected: []
    },
    methods: {
        adicionarItensSelect: function () {
            var self = this;
            self.Motivos_vinculados = self.Motivos_vinculados.concat(self.Motivos_selected);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<section id="equipamentoApp" class="content">
<div class="col-xs-1" style="width:45%">
    <label for="txtDescricao">Motivos</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="todosMotivos" v-model="Motivos_selected" style="width: 100%;">
        <option v-for="motivo in Motivos" v-bind:value="motivo">{{motivo.Descricao}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 text-center align-middle" style="width:10%">
    <br />
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-arrow-right" v-on:click.prevent="adicionarItensSelect"> -> </button></p>
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm fa fa-arrow-left" v-on:click.prevent="removerItensSelect"> <- </button></p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1" style="width:45%">
    <label for="txtDescricao">Motivos vinculados</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="selectedMotivos" v-model="Motivos_vinculados_selected" style="width: 100%;">
        <option v-for="motivo in Motivos_vinculados" v-bind:value="motivo.Codigo">{{motivo.Descricao}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</section>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pushing an entire array (Motivos_selected) into the Motivos_vinculados array. This would result in a nested array.

you should probably use:

`self.Motivos_vinculados.concat(self.Motivos_selected);`

if you want to join the two arrays, override the entire array:

`self.Motivos_vinculados = self.Motivos_selected;`

or loop through the first array and push the items to the second:

`self.Motivos_vinculados.map(item => { self.Motivos_selected.push(item) });`

EDIT---------
After looking at the fiddle, my solution was as followed:

```
adicionarItensSelect: function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Motivos_vinculados = this.Motivos.filter(motivo => {
        return self.Motivos_selected.indexOf(motivo.Codigo) !== -1;
    });
```

### }

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, @gijis-beijer ! It's not working too... I put the important part of the code on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kopq6x2f/

Comment: I see what your trying to do now. The problem lies in that a select only returns the values and not the objects.. A quick fix would be to filter the Motivos and set those to the bottom array. (I've updated the fiddle)